# URL rewriting of subdirectory to diffent port using IIS

Tags: node.js, iis, url-rewriting

I'm trying to integrate ASP.net and Node.js on a single server.
ASP.net is at localhost:8080
NodeJs is at localhost:4000

**My expectation is here.**

```
client ----> IIS Server     ----> ASP.NET (no rewriting except /api/*  localhost:80)
            (rev.0970.co.kr)  |---> Node.js (matching with /api/* localhost:4000)
```

Node app is executed as a windows service, and serve localhost:4000/api/ locally.  And should be accessed with `http://rev.0970.co.kr/api/signin`
All request excepting `/api/` should be served normal IIS asp.net. (ex. `http://rev.0970.co.kr/index.aspx`)

**My Setting Steps**
 - install ARR and UrlRewrite module
 - enable proxy of ARR
 - add rule to urlrewrite section as below.

```
        <rule name="Proxy">
            <match url="api/(.*)"/>
            <conditions>
                <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="rev.0970.co.kr" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Rewrite" url="http://localhost:4000/api/{R:1}" />
        </rule>
```

**Result**
 - http://rev.0970.co.kr/api/signin : **success**
 - http://rev.0970.co.kr/index.aspx : **fail** - 404 not found

I thought `http://rev.0970.co.kr/index.aspx` did not match  `api/(.*)`, so IIS might render index.aspx.

When I removed whole rule settings of urlrewrite, `http://rev.0970.co.kr/index.aspx` worked.

What did I do wrong?

**edit**

Here is my full web.config file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <outboundRules>
                <rule name="ReverseProxyOutboundRule1" preCondition="ResponseIsHtml1">
                    <match filterByTags="A, Form, Img" pattern="^http(s)?://localhost:4000/(.*)" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" value="http{R:1}://rev.0970.co.kr/{R:2}" />
                </rule>
                <preConditions>
                    <preCondition name="ResponseIsHtml1">
                        <add input="{RESPONSE_CONTENT_TYPE}" pattern="^text/html" />
                    </preCondition>
                </preConditions>
            </outboundRules>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Proxy">
                    <match url="api/(.*)" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="rev.0970.co.kr" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="http://localhost:4000/api/{R:1}" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
        <tracing>
            <traceFailedRequests>
                <add path="*">
                    <traceAreas>
                        <add provider="ASP" verbosity="Verbose" />
                        <add provider="ASPNET" areas="Infrastructure,Module,Page,AppServices" verbosity="Verbose" />
                        <add provider="ISAPI Extension" verbosity="Verbose" />
                        <add provider="WWW Server" areas="Security,CGI,RequestNotifications,Module,FastCGI" verbosity="General" />
                    </traceAreas>
                    <failureDefinitions timeTaken="00:00:00" statusCodes="404" />
                </add>
            </traceFailedRequests>
        </tracing>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Your rule looks good. Do you have other rules in web.config? Maybe they causing your 404 for index.aspx

Comment: @VictorLeontyev I appended whole web.config.  Could you give a adivce more?  thanks.